# How to find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{1\right\}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

This is probably a really simple question, but I cannot figure it out and it's not mentioned in my books. How do I find
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{1\right\}?\tag{1}
\end{align}
It seems like it should be so simple but I can't find anything. I've checked Wolfram Alpha and it gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20Laplace%20transform%201):
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{1\right\}=\delta\left(t\right),\tag{2}
\end{align}
the dirac delta function. Why is this? I've read the chapter on it in my textbook, *Fundamentals of Differential Equations*, and it states that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t\right)\:dt=1,\tag{3}
\end{align}
which reminds me a lot of a function like the Gaussian distribution. But how, if so, is this related to (1)?

Comment: @Amzoti okay thanks! That makes sense. Many questions I have I feel are simple but I don't regret asking and I'm glad no one downvotes me for that. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the inverse Mellin transform, we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{1\} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}e^{st}ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{u\to\infty}\int_{-iu}^{iu}e^{st}ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{e^{iut}-e^{-iut}}{s}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\sin(tu)}{t\pi}
\end{align}
[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) we see one of the identities of the Dirac Delta function is
$$
\delta(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\Bigl(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\Bigr)
$$
from equation $37$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{u}$

Comment: (part 1/2) I'll +1 to counter the downvote. But perhaps the downvoter was concerned with the expression $\lim_{u\to\infty} (\sin tu)/(t\pi)$? Note that the function $u \mapsto (\sin tu)/t\pi$ is oscillatory for $t \neq 0$ and undefined for $t = 0$, so $\lim_{u\to\infty} (\sin tu)/(t\pi)$ doesn't exist in the usual calculus sense for any $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: (part 2/2) The limit here must instead be understood in the distribution (aka generalized function) sense: The _functions_ $t \mapsto (\sin tu)/(t\pi)$ converge in the weak-$^*$ topology to the delta distribution in the limit $u \to \infty$. Explaining distributions and their topology to someone taking a first non-theoretical course in ODEs (such as OP, judging by the textbook) is a bit difficult though.

Comment: @epimorphic you are more then welcome to edit the post if you feel the need to add anything. Or you can always post a second answer with that detail. We could also skip the first sine limit by setting $\epsilon = 1/u$ in the integral and limit which would lead straight to the definition of Dirac Delta. I chose not so I could link to Wolfram and then give the substitution.